# Find the root cause of a first chance exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, exception

I am running an MVC application on the built-in VS webserver. However every time I browse a page, the output tab in Visual Studio shows a lot of exceptions.

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
An exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
An exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
An exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
```

I've attempted check all throw/usercode checkboxes of VS Exception tab under Debug Menu. It was a no go, doesn't catch anything.

How do I find the root cause of it? I would like to see stacktrace to check whether my Managed code caused it.